# Erro em programa algo relacinado com as linhas

Tags: r, ggplot2, barplot

```
energia <- data.frame("curso" = 1:15,"enem"=1:5)
energia$curso <- c("Eng Aeroespacial", "Eng Ambiental", "Eng de Controle e Automação", "Eng de Minas", "Eng de Produção", "Eng de Sistemas", "Eng   Mecânica", "Eng Metalurgica", "Geologia", "Licenciatura em Matemática","Matemática","Química","Sistema de Informação")
energia$enem <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
rotulo <- c("curso, quantidade que fez enem")
par(mgp=c(1,1,0))
barplot(energia$enem, main="enem por curso", xlab=rotulo[1],ylab=rotulo[2], names.arg = energia$curso, ylim=c(0, 100), cex.names = 0.8, xaxs = "i")


barplot(energia$curso, xlab=rotulo[1], ylab=rotulo[2], names.arg = energia$curso, ylim=c(0, 100), cex.names = 0.8,    xaxs = "i", add=TRUE)
#Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, curso, value = c("Eng Aeroespacial",  : 
#replacement has 13 rows, data has 15
```

Comment: Seu data frame `energia` e as linhas que você cria depois não tem a mesma quantidade de linhas. E é bom postar as mensagens de erro junto com as perguntas.

Comment: 1) O erro apontado pelo @JorgeMendes é o principal. Mas 2) porquê voltar a definir `enem` exatamente com os mesmos valores? 3) Porquê `ylim=c(0, 145000)` (**cento e quarenta e cinco mil!!!**) quando `max(energia$enem) == 5` e `max(energia$curso) == 15`? 4) Porquê ter o `grid` por cima das barras do `enem` e por baixo das do `curso`?

Comment: estou tentando comparar quantas vezes cada curso vez o Enem mas  mas alem dos erro das linhas eu consertei as com dicas os da linha que não mas gráfico não foi como esperei como fazer me ajude por favor

Comment: O problema, como apontado pelo JorgeMendes, está na segunda linha e tem relação com o fato de que num `data.frame` todas as coluna devem ter o mesmo tamanho. Como as primeiras tem 15 elementos a coluna `curso` também deve ter, mas tem apenas 13 valores.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para corrigir o erro dos dados da pergunta, usei a função `rep` para criar o vetor `enem`. A variável `curso` foi definida como sendo categórica ou `"factor"` para manter a ordem das barras do gráfico em baixo.

```
curso <- c("Eng Aeroespacial", "Eng Ambiental",
           "Eng de Controle e Automação", 
           "Eng de Minas", "Eng de Produção", 
           "Eng de Sistemas", "Eng   Mecânica", 
           "Eng Metalurgica", "Geologia", 
           "Licenciatura em Matemática",
           "Matemática","Química",
           "Sistema de Informação")
curso <- factor(curso, levels = curso)
enem <- rep(1:5, length.out = length(curso))
energia <- data.frame(curso, enem)
```

Quanto ao gráfico, quanto a mim é melhor usar o pacote `ggplot2`.

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(energia, aes(x = curso, y = enem)) +
  geom_col() +
  ggtitle(label = "enem por curso") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 50, hjust = 1),
        plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]